# Populate a New Account with User fields

Tags: account

I have a custom field on my User object:

Team (Picklist)

I have the same field on my accout object, and when a user creates a new account, I would like to prepopulate the Account Team field with the value in the User Team field.

How would I do that? Tia.

Comment: Is the `Team` picklist going to be editable in `Account` object (pre-populated) or read-only?

Comment: @MahmoodButt - It needs to be editable on Account.  Otherwise I would use a formula field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this with as little fuss as possible is to do it in a `before insert` trigger on Account.
Of course this means on creating a new Account, initially this will be blank. If the user enters some value in this field then this field is not overwritten. But if it is blank then it populates the field with the value from the current User record.
This will also work in case you are doing a mass insert of accounts through import wizard or data loader.

```
trigger updateTeam on Account (before insert) {

    User u = [select id,Team__c from User where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];

    for(Account acc: Trigger.new){
        if(acc.Team__c==null)
               acc.Team__c = u.Team__c;
    }        
}
```

I think the other way is to override the new Account button with a VF page and do your pre-poulation logic there.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to propose. Beat me to it.  :)